# vba: select row fails, copy of row is the main task

Tags: excel, vba

I fails at the simple task to copy a row to a different sheet with an offset of one column.

a simple

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSVImport")
    .Rows(1).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strAccount).Cells(2, 1)
```

fails because the size does not match. I assume the whole row is selected

If I select for testing only the required part

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSVImport")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, maxColumn)).Select
```

I get the error select could not be done, error 1004.

I only want to have A1:C1 copyied to B1:D1.

Comment: When it fails what is the value of `maxColumn`?

Comment: It is 11, therefore a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Scott's comment probably identified the problem; I'd bet that maxColumn is zero at the time that you do that. To populate it you should use something like:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSVImport")
    maxColumn = .Columns.Count
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, maxColumn)).Select
End With
```

***HOWEVER*** that does not deal with the fundamental problem that you can't copy an entire row and paste that into column 2 (as you said, "with an offset of one column"). It simply doesn't fit. But that having been said... that isn't what your code is trying to do anyway. Cells(2, 1) is referring to ***row*** 2, ***column*** 1; an offset of 1 row, not 1 column. The code that you posted:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSVImport")
    .Rows(1).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strAccount).Cells(2, 1)
```

actually works for me... ***provided*** that the variable strAccount is populated with a valid sheet name.

I think it may be an idea to take a step back and see what you really want to do here; whether the target is offset by 1 column or by 1 row. If it's offset by 1 column then you need to copy just the columns with data, not the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now by using this code

```
Dim target As Worksheet
Set target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1904097928")
Dim from As Worksheet
Set from = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSVImport")

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSVImport")
    Dim maxColumn As Integer
    maxColumn = Helper.lastColumn(from)
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, maxColumn)).Copy Destination:=target.Cells(1, 2)
End With
```

where lastColumn is computed as

```
Function lastColumn(sheet As Worksheet) As Integer
    lastColumn = sheet.Cells(1, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```